# Combining two phase locking and timestamping algorithm

Tags: c#, sql

I am doing a research thesis on concurrency control in distributed database. I am looking at how to efficiently improve serializability in transaction in distributed database and I want to use C# and SQL Server to implement it. I want to combine the two-phase locking algorithm with timestamp algorithm to improve serializability in distributed database.
I need ideas on how to achieve that and if possible where to start. Any form of tutorials will be a great relief.

I need ideas and tutorials on how to combine two-phase locking and timestamping algorithm

Ideas on how to combine two-phase locking and timestamping algorithm to perform on a transaction

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server already lock?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017